# Consistently Inconsistent Page Loading Times

Tags: php, performance, drupal-7, page-load-time

tl;dr: inconsistent Drupal page execution times after user performs certain actions (possibly to do with DB write).

We have a complex Drupal site running on a fairly-standard LAMP VPS setup. Among other things, we are using Rules to provide a great deal of custom functionality, as well as User Relationships, Organic Groups and custom modules. PHP is running under Apache (mod_php) and MemCache and APC are enabled (though APC was not enabled when this issue was first noticed).

Here's the problem: having experienced inconsistent page load times (sometimes good - 200ms, sometimes only barely acceptable - 4,000ms, sometimes abominably unacceptable - 20,000ms) we coded a timer to display custom PHP execution times on-page. The times we saw were uniformly acceptable; both on very simple pages and also on ones where a great deal of back-end processing had occurred due to the user's actions on the previous page. However, the intermittent page load problem persisted - the system was sometimes taking fifteen seconds to serve the page (time-to-first-byte) even though the processing had been demonstrably performed in a tiny fraction of that time.

In fact, we were able to see that Drupal was processing code rapidly in other ways; for instance, an email (triggered by Rules) would arrive in an inbox ten seconds or more before the user who triggered the rule got to see the confirmation page! Similarly, when a Rules action or User Relationships caused a change in a user object's custom field, that change would be visible to an administrator while the user's browser was still waiting for data.

We were able to consistently predict when these long page load times would occur:

- Only after a user performed a individually-specific action, such as confirming a new "friend" (via User Relationships), performing an action only available to a member of a group (via Rules / Organic Groups) or something causing one of our custom modules to perform actions on the user object. General site navigation appears normally OK.
- Regardless of the number or combination of modules involved (Rules and/or OG and/or UR and/or custom modules)
- Regardless of the page to be loaded - the page experiencing a long load time could be a very simple static page ("you have successfully done X") or a complex construction such as a list of all a user's friends and their details.

We can tentatively draw the following conclusions:

- PHP/Drupal processing speed is not at fault (we know all processing is being taken care of quickly).
- General server tuning is not at fault (otherwise all page loads would likely be sluggish).
- Page complexity is not a significant factor.
- Internet connection speed is not a significant factor.
- No specific single or apparent combination of modules is at fault.
- There is some factor that we're not considering, or don't know enough about to pin down the precise cause.

We think this may be a caching issue, but note that this happens only where a user's actions cause a database write... Does this scenario sound familiar/explicable to anyone?

Comment: I had this problem before (but not on a Drupal site) and it turned out that the hard drive was almost out of space. Worth a check at least

Comment: What happens when you do the same operation 2 times?  is it fast the second time?

Comment: Re - Hard Drive: Nope not this, we are on a VPS and have gigs of available space.

Comment: Re - repeated operations. This does not seem to always be a factor; similar operations that cause and email to be sent do not have a reduced time on repetition. Operations where we set a connection, delete it and then set the exact same connection also do not reduce in time.  There are exceptions to this; (1) User A adds User B (script RT 6 sec-vbad, page reload 20sec).  (2) Delete connection. (3) User A adds User B (script RT 0.18 sec-vgood, page reload 15sec). (4) User A adds User C (script RT 0.17 sec-vgood, page reload 15sec).

Answer (score 0):

install [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) on your Webserver, if possible, and monitor the logs. See if you can pin it down to a specific function to confirm your suspicions regarding SQL.

Try to replicate the issue on another machine.

It sounds like its your VPS's problem. Contact them, get them to move you to a different cluster or investigate the problem.

Comment: XDebug installed via Host tech, we lacked the necessary clearance.  Any advice on what to turn on/off to look for specifics.

Comment: You primarily want the [profiler](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler). this will show you how long every function call takes to complete. You specifically want to look for function calls that take a long time, from there you can see whats going on and investigate alternative methods. Just so you know, while you are logging performance will decrease. Good luck!

Comment: We have solved this without getting an exact fix on the cause.  Set of measures such as refining APC and other caching.

Answer (score 0):

Enable slow log (if using mysql)

```
log_slow_queries=/var/log/mysql/slow-query.log
long_query_time=10
log_queries_not_using_indexes=YES
```

(restart database)

If it is database related this should give you some clues.

Also check if it uses too much memory and it start to swap ( use htop for this.)

Comment: MySQL is pretty snappy, from the devel module which gives us query time and the performance module which confirms rapid MySQL behaviour.